# solr CSV update, overwrite parameter

Tags: solr

I'm trying to get the CSV import working for SOLR, and having a problem with the overwrite parameter. I'm following the documentation here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV#overwrite, and what I find is that I get duplicates in my index, even when I specify overwrite. I'm starting with a dead simple case where I import 1 record, modify a description field in the CSV and then import it again with &overwrite=true. The resulting SOLR query produces 2 records. Is this a bug? Using SOLR 4.2.

Comment: what is your schema, specifically show your uniqueKey element definition

Comment: UniqueKey is set to content_id, which is a keyword tokenizer with lowercase filter in the schema. in my Csv I don't touch this column, only the description column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, it was not related to the CSV update endpoint, but rather how I had my uniqueKey field defined in the schema. The following did not work:

```
<field name="id" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

But it did work when I changed the type to string:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

As far as I can tell, this is not documented behavior anywhere on the SOLR wiki.